# Conexión a base de datos en servidor

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

estoy tratando de hacer conexión a una base de datos que se encuentra en un servidor (el proyecto que estoy trabajando es local), pero al hacer el php de dicha conexión me aparece el siguiente error:
**Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto_IP\php\config.php on line 6**

Este es el código que empleo:

```
<?php
    $server = "http://10.245.36.52/phpmyadmin/index.php?token=8758ed1be21fea96c15fb96236ff0be1";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "phpipam";
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$password,$database);
?>
```

¿Alguien me puede colaborar?

Comment: Le puedes hacer ping a esa IP desde local?

Comment: @LuisFernando, hace ping con esa dirección ip, pero no reconoce host si lo intento como lo tengo en la variable $server

Comment: Si abres esa URL en Postman o en el navegador, qué mensaje obtienes?

Comment: Si entro a esa dirección voy a tener el formulario de inicio de phpmyadmin donde va a solicitar usuario y contraseña

Comment: El problema es que estás especificando URL de una página y no del servidor MySQL, son cosas muy diferentes, PhpMyAdmin no es servidor de base de datos, solo un cliente. Prueba con `$server = 'localhost';`

Comment: @Triby, lo intenté y ahora obtengo este error: "Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto_IP\php\config.php on line 6
"

Comment: Excelente, ya vas avanzando, ahora solo necesitas especificar usuario y contraseña correctos, te van a servir los mismos que usas para acceder a PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: Estoy usando el usuario y contraseña de PhpMyAdmin pero no me permite conectarme

Comment: Solo por descartar, ¿estás usando usuario y contraseña de un servidor web o de tu servidor local?

Comment: Estoy usando usuario y contraseña del servidor web, del PhpMyAdmin, pero marca error como si estuviera escribiendo mal alguna de esas dos credenciales

Answer (score 0):

algunos comentarios fueron de ayuda, lo único que necesitaba el código para hacer la conexión era esto:

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "bd_ip";
$conexion = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$password,$database);
?>
```

No entiendo porqué, pero no arroja ningún error y permite la conexión perfectamente sin ninguna clave de acceso.